# How to convert VS code from UTF-16 to UTF-8

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, character, utf

I don't know why but my VS code in the bottom line report UTF-16 LE and I want UTF-8.
This gives me many problems with JS file.
What do I have to do to change that value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bottom bar of VSCode, you'll see the label UTF-16 LE. Click it. A popup opens. Click Save with encoding. You can now pick a new encoding for that file.